# How to disuse Delay Function it cause a bad effect (how to solve this scenario)?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have one scenario problem and I don't want to use interrupts cause the same problem will be there I will be forced to use delay to insure that specific time did pass.

the problem:

I don't want to use the delay function cause it stops the other tasks to be checked or executed taking a situation:

I have motor that run 6 seconds if button1 is pressed and if a man press button2 the motor 2 immediately need to be turned on and work for 2 second.

so the code will be like this:

```
main ()
{

if( Rd0 == 0 )   // is button1 is pressed
{
RunMotre1(); 

__delay_ms(6000);
StopMotor1();

}


if( Rd1 == 0 )  // is button2 is pressed
{
RunMotor2();
__delay_ms(2000);
StopMotor2();
}

}
```

the problem of this code if we pressed the button b to start Motor 2 he will 
not work cause the system is blocked on  delay  and wait it to be finished .

and that cause that if we start -> press button 1->motor 1 runing -> pressing buTTon2 to start Motor2-> Motor2 not working until the 6 seconds be passed.

so is there a way to resolve this problem case.

for example if exists comparing who mutch time  Motor1 did run if is greate or = 6 secound then stop the motor 1 example (samthing like this if exist)  :

```
Time counter1;
Time Counter2;

main()
{ 


if( Rd0 == 0 )     // is button 1 to start motor1 is presed ?
{
RunMotre1(); 

counter1.start();
}


if(counter1.CurentElapsedTimes==6 Secound)   // is motor1 did run 6 seconds
{
counter1.stop();
counter1.Initialise();

StopMotor1();
}

if( Rd1 == 0 )        // is button 2 to start motor2 is pressed.
RunMotor2();
counter2.start();
}

if(counter2.CurentElapsedTimes==2 Secound)   // is motor2 did run 2 seconds
{
counter2.stop();
counter2.Initialise();

StopMotor2();
}
```

or any solution

platform pic microcontroller  using xc8 compiler

Answer (score 0):

PRESUPPOSITION: I don't know which PIC you are using, but I assume that it has at least a free timer.

The problem here is that you need something to track the time as it passes. My suggestion is to use the same technique that the Arduino FW uses: setup a timer to fire an interrupt every X milliseconds/seconds, then in the interrupt service routine (ISR) update a counter.

When you press the button set the counter, then wait for the counter to reach another value before turning the motor off.

I'll write here a small pseudo-code example, since I don't remember how to properly write an ISR with a PIC compiler nor I know what is your PIC (and, so, the commands to initialize the timer).

I chose to use a timer granularity of 100ms, but you can change it as you prefer.
I also chose to set `counter` as a 8-bit variable; it can count up to 25.5 seconds, but since the highest delay is 6 seconds it's ok.

Note that you need just ONE timer, so you can add any number of motors without the need for adding counters

```
char counter;
char motor1StartTime;
char motor2StartTime;
bool motor1Running;
bool motor2Running;

Timer1_ISR()
{
    counter++;
}

main()
{ 
    counter = 0;
    motor1StartTime = 0;
    motor2StartTime = 0;
    motor1Running = false;
    motor2Running = false;

    // Setup the timer to trigger the Timer1_ISR every 100ms
    ...

    while(1)
    {
        if( Rd0 == 0 )
        { // If the button is pressed start the motor and save the counter
            RunMotor1(); 
            motor1StartTime = counter;
            motor1Running = true;
        }

        if ((motor1Running) && ((counter - motor1StartTime) >= 60))
        { // If the motor is running from more than 6 seconds, shut it down
            StopMotor1();
            motor1Running = false;
        }


        if( Rd1 == 0 )
        { // If the button is pressed start the motor and save the counter
            RunMotor2(); 
            motor2StartTime = counter;
            motor2Running = true;
        }

        if ((motor2Running) && ((counter - motor2StartTime) >= 20))
        { // If the motor is running from more than 2 seconds, shut it down
            StopMotor2();
            motor2Running = false;
        }
    }
}
```